# Find the numerical value of the 2nd positive solution of a Bessel Function

Tags: special-functions, numerical-value

A) Find the numerical value of the 2nd positive solution of $J_2 (3x)=0$ to at least 5 significant digits

Note: $J_n(y)$ represents a Bessel function, which is written as `BesselJ[n,y]` in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[BesselJ[2, 3 x], {x, 0, 5}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, y],
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[BesselJ[2, 3 x] == 0 && x > 0, x, Reals, 
  GeneratedParameters -> c] /. c[1] -> 2
N[%, 5]
```

> {{x -> 1/3 BesselJZero[2, 2]}}

> {{x -> 2.8057}}

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. Would you be able to help with part 2? Find the first maximum value of (J subscript 2)(3x) to at least 5 significant digits.

Comment: @LeLe  Maybe  `FindMaximum[BesselJ[2, 3 x], {x, 0, 2}]`

Comment: @LeLe  `NSolve[D[BesselJ[2, 3 x], x] == 0 && 
  D[BesselJ[2, 3 x], {x, 2}] <= 0  && 0 < x < 2, x, Reals]` is another way.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Look up `BesselJZero`.

```
BesselJZero[2, 2]/3.
(*  2.80575  *)
```